# Rose's Answers to Corners (Ultra Street Fighter IV)

Tags: ultra-street-fighter-iv

I'm fairly new to USFIV, but after playing about 10 hours, I've decided to learn Rose as my first character. Having gone through the majority of her trials, and played through Arcade mode a couple times, I found her to have a really solid zoning game, with some decent anti-airs.

One problem of hers I haven't found a solution for, though, is her answer to being trapped in a corner. While blocking is certainly an option, I'd like to find some way for her to reliably get out of a corner with as little risk as possible. The best thing I've found is a Soul Satellite to give her a chance for a mixup or a throw, but that requires at least half of an ultra gauge, and can't be used often in a match. Other possible alternatives include an EX Soul Throw, more or less used to jump away from the opponent, and a Soul Spiral. The main problem with both of these is the risk involved, as Soul Throw could be punished relatively easily, while Soul Spiral isn't invincible on startup, and the Heavy version is unsafe on block.

So, my question is, what is Rose's safest, most reliable way to get out of a corner against high-pressure rushdown style characters, without needing the ultra gauge? While "Don't let yourself get trapped in the corner in the first place" is certainly a valid response, I'm trying to figure out a solution for when I do get myself pushed up against a wall.

Answer (score 1):

I think rose definitely has that zoning advantage over most if not all the characters, which character trapped you in the corner would be my initial question. Rose can simply use standing pokes HK HP, etc to push opponent further into his sides. fireball anti-air, is the best zoning technique, if you aren't worried about losing some hp, then i would say slide meaty would get u into point blank range, then jump cross up to escape would be harder to react.

Answer (score 0):

EX Soul Drill is very useful-as is HP soul reflect. Her focus backdash is fast enough to recover as well. Really, it will end up depending on your opponent. She doesn't have a "shoryuken" escape, so you have to play the opponent's tendencies.